# Why does sklearn require the true labels when implementing the rand index ?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have been looking into evaluating the accuracy of my clusters and Rand Index appears to be one that is hugely popular in the literature. It is calculated by making a pairwise comparison of each item in each cluster and assigning a score to them based on four criteria: True positive , true negative , false positive and false negative or a , b , c , d. The Rand score is calculated by taking the sum of the true positive and true negatives and dividing them by the sum of all the above mentioned classes.

My question is , why does sklearn then require the correct labels to calculate the Rand Index Score ?

Comment: Without the correct labels, how do you know if its a false positive, true negative, or true positive?

Comment: fp tp and tp are determined using the pairwise comparison. If two items are the same in one set then A is incremented by one. Equally if they are both differ they are considered negatives, and score is determined from there.

Answer (score 0):

Rand index etc. require the true labels (precisely, they require *two* sets of labels, and compute how much they agree). So there is nothing wrong with the sklearn implementation.

A pair (x,y) is positive if label1(x)==label1(y) AND label2(x)==label2(y).
The other three cases follow from switching to inequality.